# 7-zip "incorrect command" on context menu

Tags: windows-7, compression, context-menu, 7-zip, archiving

I installed the latest version of 7-zip in a clean install of Windows 7 and all of the context menu items for "create archive" result in `Incorrect command line`.  I've uninstalled it, and installed the version I was running on my previous Windows install (v9.2 x64) and it seems 7-zip has buggered the registry on my clean install.

How do I get this damn thing to actually work?

**EDIT** -- it *does* work to create archives within the 7-Zip file manager, but that's a pain.  It's just the Explorer context menu actions that don't work.

Comment: Delete the context menu registries in regedit and then reinstall 7zip.

Comment: What was the method of installing 7-zip?  Ninite?  Standard installer downloaded from a site?  Which site?

Comment: @Biswapriyo: which keys are those?

Comment: @ChristopherHostage: installer from the official 7-zip site.

Comment: Registry: `HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\7-Zip`. Also replace the star ( * ) with Directory, Drive, Folder.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: they were already deleted from the registry.  Reinstalled 7-zip and now it works.  Maybe it just needed a reboot.